# Share PDF from assets. FileUriExposedException

Tags: android, android-assets, android-fileprovider

I want to open PDF, which is in interaly saved in app/assets/pdf_name.pdf

I get the file using 
`File f = new File(getContext().getCacheDir() + /pdf_name.pdf");`

I'm trying to extract URI if form of **content://** using

`Uri pdfUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "pcg_name.fileprovider", file);`

but I got

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root
>   that contains
>   /data/data/pck_name/cache/pdf_name.pdf

ALthout I've configurated

```
<paths>
    <cache-path
        name="my_documents"
        path="assets/"/>
    <cache-path
        name="my_pdf"
        path="cache/"/>
</paths>
```

My goal is to open PDF via Intent, but I can not do just:

```
Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(pdfFile),"application/pdf");
target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
target.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // DON'T FORGET this
```

Because it throws File Uri exposed exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the file using

That code has nothing to do with assets. Assets are files on your development machine; they are not files on the device, unless you manually copy the content to a file.

Perhaps you have code, not shown in the question, where you copied the file from assets to `new File(getContext().getCacheDir() + /pdf_name.pdf")`.

> ALthout I've configurated

Neither of those are valid for `new File(getContext().getCacheDir() + /pdf_name.pdf")`. Delete one `<cache-path>` element and get rid of the `path` attribute from the other `<cache-path>` element, leaving you with:

```
<paths>
  <cache-path name="my_pdf"/>
</paths>
```

Comment: You save'd my day. I was close because when I type just name at first time, Android Studio highlighted error: that it should contain path, so I abandoned this idea. However it compiles, and after all works.